# How to wrap (compose) a boost hana map and access the bracket operator (operator[])?

Tags: c++, boost-hana

I'm using a hana map (created using `hana::make_map`). I have a very simple class that would inherit from the hana map, and expose a second map as such

```cpp
auto values = hana::make_map( ... );
auto uncertainties = hana::make_map( ... );

template< typename Values, typename Uncertainty >
struct map: Values{
  Uncertainty uncertainty;
  constexpr map(Values v, Uncertainty u ):
    Values( v ),
    uncertainty( u )
  { }
};

auto data = map( values, uncertainties );

// I want to do the following

auto hbar = data[ hbar ]; // Type hbar defined elsewhere
auto hbar_u = data.uncertainty[ hbar ]
```

This used to work. I recently updated our version of boost hana and now I get the following compiler error:

```
map.hpp:2:13: error: base
      'map_impl' is marked 'final'
struct map: Values{
            ^
```

If I understand this message correctly, boost hana has explicitly been marked so that I can no longer inherit.

**What I really want to do is use the `operator[]` to access the values map and use `.uncertainty` to access the uncertainties map.** How do I do this?

I really don't want to have to use any other boost library; hana is more than enough for my project.

Comment: I've never seen `hana::map`, but then wouldn't it be `template<class key_type> auto operator[](key_type&& key) -> decltype(values[key]) {return values[key];}` ?

Comment: I've updated my question a bit to show what I want to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's typically preferred to use an aggregate vs inheritance.

As "Mooing Duck" stated in the comments, you can just use a function to forward
the `operator[]` to the `values` map.

Looking at the implementation of `operator[]` in Boost.Hana you'll notice there is an overload for each value type since `this` cannot be deduced. (They should fix that)

Casting `values` to the appropriate reference type will allow you to return references of the correct value type if that is needed. This will make it behave exactly like `hana::map`.

```
#define BOOST_HANA_CONFIG_ENABLE_STRING_UDL 1
#include <boost/hana.hpp>

namespace hana = boost::hana;
using namespace hana::literals;

template <typename Values, typename Uncertainty>
struct my_map_t {
  Values values;
  Uncertainty uncertainty;
  
  constexpr decltype(auto) operator[](auto&& key) & {
    return static_cast<Values&>(values)[
        std::forward<decltype(key)>(key)];
  }
  constexpr decltype(auto) operator[](auto&& key) && {
    return static_cast<Values&&>(values)[
        std::forward<decltype(key)>(key)];
  }
  constexpr decltype(auto) operator[](auto&& key) const& {
    return static_cast<Values const&>(values)[
        std::forward<decltype(key)>(key)];
  }
};

// Note: Clang 10 does not provide implicit deduction guides yet

constexpr auto values = hana::make_map(
  hana::make_pair("foo"_s, 42) 
);

constexpr auto uncertainties = hana::make_map(
  hana::make_pair("bar"_s, 5)
);


constexpr auto my_map = my_map_t(values, uncertainties);

static_assert(my_map["foo"_s] == 42);
static_assert(my_map.uncertainty["bar"_s] == 5);

int main() { }
```

https://godbolt.org/z/XVNsy-

---

If you want to use boring, old C++17:

https://godbolt.org/z/i-NZd6

Comment: I should have mentioned that I'm using C++17. I believe the link you gave for godbolt.org  uses c++2a. When I changed this to C++17, the compilation failed.

Comment: I think the only differences are the implicit argument deduction guide and the concise function template syntax.

Comment: I added a link to a C++17 version. :D

Comment: Thanks for putting up the C++17 version. I can see that it compiles just fine. I'm trying to do the same with my [real code](https://github.com/njoy/constants/blob/fix/map/src/constants/CODATA2018.hpp), but I keep getting the message: `constexpr variable must be initialized by a constant expression`

Comment: I resolved the issue I came here for. Your answer helped a lot! Now I just have to figure out how to get the keys from the hana::map.